# Multithreading application versus active sql session

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, session

I have a C# application that is running multi-threaded (`Parallel.ForEach`) with 16 maximum concurrent threads. I can see it is working fine because the performance of the execution time is definitely faster. However, I am wondering why it is only showing less than 16 active sessions on the SQL Server monitor tool? The bizarre part is for the same application (similar set up except they are using SQL Server 2012 instead of our SQL Sever 2008R2) running on our customer's machine, the same tool report more than 30 active session monitored. Since I can't access our customer's enviornment, I am wondering:

1. Why are there only a few active sessions be found (usually less than 5) on the SQL Server while we have 16 threads running concurrently?

2. Why then are there are more than 30 active sessions reported on our customer machine? They claim the system is very isolated that only has our application access at that moment...

The first one is the chart when running on my environment:
[image: Here is the chart when running on my environment:]

vs this chart when running on our customer's environment:
[image: Here is the chart when running on our customer's environment:]

Thanks for the comment, and here I am trying to provide more information:
I. This is confirmed the application is running single instance, and it is a console desktop application.
II. This is basically a datawarehouse migration, which it download an xml file from a server, and using the same connection string on each thread (inside parallel.foreach and import the data using NHibernate, this part of code is like a blackbox to me since I am not familar with Nhibernate, I just call an in-house dll to carry out this function)
III. I really don't have much information about my customer's machine but I knew they have a more powerful machine than my test server which mine is already a 16GB Quadcore 64 bits Win7. The only big difference is they are using SQL Server 2012 and my test server (who is running the application) is also my SQL 2008 R2 server (i.e. the Datawarehouse client DB repository).
IV. I do understand each connection string should share one pool, but I have no clue why the same monitor tool is showing so much different number of sessions between me and my customer's environment.

Comment: How do you access your database? How do you create your db connection? I assume all the connections are sharing the same connection string?

Comment: By c# application do you mean a Windows desktop application? If so, how many instances of the c# application are there that connect to the database.

Comment: We need a LOT more information to help you there. Sample code of how you access the application, configuration of the thread and connection pools. Editions used for sql server, edition of Windows OS running the DB and the server/client (or either if only 1 applies) etc. It could be plenty of things (hitting the limit of pooled connections, hitting the default limit of threads if using the thread pool and they have a lot less core than you etc). it could be pretty much everything! Give us some code and a lot more ifnormation on both environments software/hardware, not much can be guessed else.

Comment: have you looked up C# `Connection Pooling with Sql Server` from my understanding when you think that you're creating multiple connections in C# which is different than lets Say Delphi which can handle true multiple connection pooling where as C# .NET they dropped the ball on this one...

Comment: Another possible factor is the number of cpu cores available on the different servers.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are a bad programmer your code will open and close database connections only when it needs them, using a using construct.

And if the tasks do something else than read and write data this means that they will not keep the connection open all the time.

Which means it is naturally you see less open connections - basically the size of the connection pool that is active. It will not reach the sam e as the size of tasks because they are not used all the time.

Comment: Yup. I understand that probably can explain for my local environment. However, why it has such big different when it is running on my customer's environment (since they are testing with the same application and connection string)?

Comment: What environment? What load? Yes, it can have a serious effect. Start profiling ON YOUR CUSTOMERS ENVIRONMENT.